# Laravel : Undefined index: driver

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I need to change database dynamically,
For example, there are two databases,`db1` and `db2`,there is a table `articles` in each database.

Now I want to copy articles from `db1` to `db2`,

in `.env` file, the  current database is `db1`:

```
DB_DATABASE=db1
```

I want to change it dynamically when copying records, I tried to do it like this:

```
public function test()
{
    $articles=Article::all();

    Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "database" => "db2",
        "username" => "root",
        "password" => ""
    ]);
    //DB::purge('mysql');  //this line exists or not,it has the same error.
    DB::table('articles')->insert($articles);
    dd('ok');
}
```

but there is an error:

> Undefined index: driver

I have many databases, so I don't want to change it in `.env` file.
What should I do?

**update:**

in `config/database.php` it has the two items:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

],
```

and I try

```
    Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
       'mysql' => [
           "host" => "127.0.0.1",
           "database" => "db2",
           "username" => "root",
           "password" => ""
        ]
    ]);
```

The error still exists.

Comment: Have you checked `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')` present in **config/database.php** ?

Comment: @Sagar Gautam it has this item.

Comment: One way is to use DB::connection() with creating a new connection to database.

Comment: @Sagar Gautam but  this way need write database name into config/database.php,I have many datatases.

Comment: Then it will be a problem to write whole connection over there,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because you are missing the `driver` in your configuration.

A better way of changing the connection would be registering your new connection in database configuration file and change the connection at runtime.

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'newConnection' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'db2',
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
]
```

Now you can change your connection using the name you used to define your new connection.

Change the default connection

```
Config::set('database.default', 'newConnection');
DB::reconnect('newConnection');
```

or change the connection for a query builder

```
DB::connection('newConnection')->table('articles')->insert($articles);
```

or if you are using Eloquent models you can set the default connection associated with the model using the `connection` property

```
protected $connection = 'newConnection';
```

or change at runtime by calling `setConnection`

```
(new User)->setConnection('newConnection');
```

If you wish to change the current connection details you can change them as you wish

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'db2');
```

and after changes you need to call

```
DB::reconnect('mysql');
```

or

```
DB::purge('mysql');
```

Comment: `Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'db2');`it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function test()
{
    $articles=Article::all();

    Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
        "driver" => "mysql"
        "host" => "127.0.0.1",
        "database" => "db2",
        "username" => "root",
        "password" => ""
    ]);
    //DB::purge('mysql');  //this line exists or not,it has the same error.
    DB::table('articles')->insert($articles);
    dd('ok');
}
```

you were missing the driver , as laravel needs what driver of database you want to use, as you are using database.connection.mysql it will set the values in that array, but still the driver is needed

```
as for example 


'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),

        ],
```

Comment: I don't understand.the defalut config file has `'driver' => 'mysql'`,see my update.

Comment: you are putting it by yourself bro, thus you need to pass the array key value pair.

Comment: I have many databases.Assuming I have 200 databases,thus I will add 200  items.I don't want to do it like this.

Comment: what you dont want too?? you are just adding the driver index to your code only, see the upper portion of the ans, i have just added a driver value to your code only, and nothing else

Comment: @zwl1619 As I know, database array should be identical to the way it is declared on the configuration file. So please try connecting with adding all key values pair as in default connection

Comment: @Exprator I see. I misunderstand.

Comment: Hope could have helped you :) @zwl1619

Answer (score 0):

In my case driver was configured as well as everything else but it threw that error when I hit any endpoint. I was not able to delete cache with php artisan command so for me solution was to manually delete cache files from app/bootstrap/cache folder as old configuration stayed there and did not recognized new database connection.