# PDO Firebird does not start when called from within Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, firebird

Yes, cache is cleared:

> INFO  Configuration cache cleared successfully.

Thanks for the comments, I edit and try to complete:

1. Driver DLL is in PHP directory and .\ext sudbir. Runs well when called directly from PHP. Paths are complete and tested.
2. Is EMAIL a constant you defined? It is just a field in the queried table. Loads well from PHP, not seen from Laravel because the connection does not open.
3. Laravel config that doesn't work:

   env

   ```
   DB_CONNECTION=firebird
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT=3050
   DB_DATABASE=D:/etsol/nutritronix/nutritronix.fdb
   DB_USERNAME=SYSDBA
   DB_PASSWORD=masterkey
   ```

   Database.php (Firebird section)

   ```
   'firebird' => [
       'driver' => 'firebird',
       'dsn' => 'firebird:dbname=D:/etsol/nutritronix/nutritronix.fdb;charset=UTF8',
       'host' => '127.0.0.1',
       'port' => '3050',
       'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'SYSDBA'),
       'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'masterkey'),
       'charset' => 'UTF8',
       'role' => null,
   ],
   ```
4. Environment notes:

   - Win 10
   - PHP 8.2.8
   - Laravel 10
   - Firebird 2.5

   All in 64 bit

Impossible to connect to Firebird from Laravel. PHP alone connects perfect with the syntax below.

Laravel complains:

> 1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php:148
> >Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap{closure}("Undefined array key "driver"", "D:\AsusCloud\Electronica\Arduino\Development\LaravelProjects\nutritronix-1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager.php")

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';       // Replace with your Firebird server address
$database = 'd:/etsol/nutritronix/NU_V2.fdb'; // Replace with the path to your Firebird database file
$username = 'SYSDBA';      // Replace with your Firebird username
$password = 'masterkey';   // Replace with your Firebird password

try {
    $dsn = "firebird:host=$host;dbname=$database;charset=UTF8";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    // Optional: Set error handling mode to exceptions
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Now you can use $pdo to interact with the Firebird database
    // For example, you can execute queries or fetch data from tables.
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Execute a query
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM DEVICES");
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // Process each row of data
    // Access fields using $row['column_name']
    echo $row[EMAIL];
}
```

Comment: Where is `driver` being used as a key?

Comment: Is `EMAIL` a constant you defined?

Comment: Have you added a driver for Firebird, eg https://packagist.org/packages/harrygulliford/laravel-firebird? Laravel doesn't support it out-of-the-box.

Comment: Duplication?.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066886/laravel-undefined-index-driver